# debian 10 / lxde / tight vnc - copy paste from windows in both directions not working

Tags: debian, gui, vnc, lxde, remote-desktop

We are moving from windows server to debian 10, we need a gui for a while until we transition to full command line.

we need to vnc (lxde gui) into the debian server and be able to copy and paste files etc (share windows clipboard)
Is this possible?
If so how? i've enabled the options in tight vnc but it still doesn't work

The debian boxes are in cloud and not local so we always access the gui using vnc

I installed autocutsel and have this in my /root/.vnc/xstartup

```
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
autocutsel -fork
#/usr/bin/autocutsel -s CLIPBOARD -fork
lxterminal &
/usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE &
```

but it still wont work.

I've also tried running: `autocutsel -s CLIPBOARD -fork`
direct from terminal when in gui, but i still cannot access clipboard in any direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if VNC supports this (From my understanding of the technical how it works docs that I read a few years ago, probably not). I may be wrong on this part, as I see you have enabled the options.

However there are alternatives.
Consider these alternatives

- RDP.
- XtoGo I hear it is the better of the 3 (don't know if it runs on MS-Windows).
- Mounting remote file-system locally, or local file-system remotely.
- `ssh -X` You will need to be running the X11 windowing system locally.

Comment: thanks, went with RDP and it works great, i had to disable sharing drives etc on MS RDP options as it loaded with black screen, but after this and reboot of debian it works fine!